# Auto filled Current Password on Change Password page

Tags: autocomplete, passwords, change-password

I'm testing a page for "Change Password".
The user I've logged in with has already saved the Password with browser.
The problem is that whenever I open the "Change Password" page, the Current Password is shown to be filled in already.
I'm not sure this is an issue or is correct.
Please help me whether this is an issue or is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the attribute below to your password input.

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Please note though that latest versions of major browsers are not supporting this attribute any more.

Answer (score 0):

First, I guess it would be better if you put your code.
Secondly, if the password is already filled maybe the value attribute in your input is not empty! Check it out :)
Example:

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="someValue">
```

Comment: I'm a QA so don't know about the code. :). Just wanted to know the above scenario I mentioned is a defect or not.

Comment: Then maybe you clicked [save password] the first time you logged in on this page. Here is the method [How to Remove a Saved Password from a Browser] http://www.bu.edu/tech/services/support/desktop/software/troubleshooting/removing-password-from-browsers-saved-password-list/

Comment: I just need to know whether the point I raised above is a bug or not.
Scenario is mentioned below:
1. I have stored the Log-in credentials (Email & Password) in browser.
2. Now while I go to "Change Password" page, the Email field on this page is shown auto filled by browser.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for those still looking for an answer, you can use the attribute `autofill='new-password'`.

Complete example;

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```